# How to add data provider values in testng extent-report version 2.41.2(relevantcodes)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng-dataprovider, extentreports

I have used Dataprovider to pass my test values and I want these values to get displayed in my testNG extent report. I have seven test cases and these test cases run on multiple test values passed in DataProvider. By clicking on the method name in extent report, I want the report to display that on which values the test has been executed.`

Here is my dataprovider class:

```
public class MyDataProvider {

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] realTimeConfiguration() {
        return new Object[][] {

                 new Object[] {"safari", "safari5.1","macoslion" },
                new Object[] { "chrome", "chrome76", "win10", "1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome75","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome74","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome73","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome72","win10","1280x1024" },

                 new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox68","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox67","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox66","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox65","win10","1280x1024" },
                 new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox64","win10","1280x1024" },

        };

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: We are using [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io) and it is showing test data from dataprovider in qaf report.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider logging the values manually through a base class method - for example

```
public class MyTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test(dataProvider = "realTimeConfiguration", dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
    public void verifySomething(String browser, String userAgent, String platform, String resolution) {
        logToReport(String.format("Test started for: Browser: '%s', userAgent: '%s', platform: '%s', resolution: '%s'"));
    }
}
```